# Where I download the Pentaho Community Edition, link breadk on sourceforge

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

Before downloading some Pentaho Community Edition and its products using the link placed on Sourceforge, **the link is broken today March 2024.**

Answer (score -1):

I found the site, the link to download the Pentaho Community Edition and its products is **https://www.hitachivantara.com/pentaho/pentaho-plus-platform/data-integration-analytics/pentaho-community-edition.html**